# npm install error in laravel nova component

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-sass, laravel-nova

I just want to create a component for laravel nova but got following errors during npm install process. I've tried to install node-sass in other projects without problems but in this component, I'll get the same error.

be aware of different project name in package.json and composer.json as in the error log - I've tried another name for my component here, but the error is still the same.

Hope someone can help.. in my office, nobody know what I could do not know this error could happen. Sit there for a while now.

What I've done till now?

- reinstall nodejs/npm
- updated/reinstalled MSBuild Tools (2017 / 2019 / 2022)
- reinstalled python2
- reinstalled git
- checked my environment variables
- deleted component and created new one, even with other names
- tried different terminals (windows cmd, mingw64)

Versions of Software

- npm version 8.3.0
- nodejs v17.3.0 (even tried with version 16)
- python 2.7
- Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 v15.9.42
- Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 v16.11.8
- Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 v17.0.4 (but i think it isn't necessary?)
- Windows 10 21H1 (Build 19043.1288)

Error Message

```
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up 
to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\dev\vierol-shop-relaunch\nova-components\Test\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\dev\vierol-shop-relaunch\nova-components\Test\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=     
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\dev\\vierol-shop-relaunch\\nova-components\\Test\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.3.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2.exe C:\Python27\python2.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python2.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 17.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '17.3.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "17.3.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 17.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 17.3.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\dev\vierol-shop-relaunch\nova-components\Test\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\dev\vierol-shop-relaunch\nova-components\Test\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7
```

comopser.json

```
{
    "name": "vs/test",
    "description": "A Laravel Nova card.",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "nova"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vs\\Test\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Vs\\Test\\CardServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.5.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what version of node-sass it's trying to install, but my guess from the node-gyp 3.8 that it's something around 4.x, so the newest version of Node it likely supports is 14 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: thanks. that helped a lot. someone said he can even build with node 17 but I think his configuration isn't correct. but it doesn't matter, with node14 I can work for now. thanks for that.

Comment: Node 14 worked for me too! :)